# Mac OSX: opening .cc files with MacVim instead of Xcode by default

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode, source-code, macvim

In Mac OSX 10.6.4, I'm trying to change the default application for opening .cc files from Xcode to MacVim, but Xcode or OSX won't abide. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Notice how the clicking "Change All..." to MacVim results in the dialogue asking me to confirm the switch to *Xcode* - it's really hogging those files!

Why is this / is there any other way to change this?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the dialog is not simply displaying the wrong App name - that if you click continue, then try to open a cc file, it will still open with Xcode?

Comment: It still opens i Xcode. Tried quitting Xcode too, doesn't work

Comment: It worked after rebooting - guess that would have been quicker than posting the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot did the trick... obviously ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the default application using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/).

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try downloading [Onyx](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/onyx.html), then going to Maintenance -> Rebuild and choosing to reset "LaunchServices".  This is a bit of a drastic solution, as it'll reset *all* document->app mappings, but it may help you do what you need, too.

Comment: This answer should probably by HUGELY more caveated. He's going to lose ANY non-default association, and could potentially be inundated with associations problems after running that mapping reset.